# Datetime fields appear garbled in Solr

Tags: solr, indexing

I'm on **Solr 4.10.4**, **Sitecore 8.1 160519**.

I have a custom index defined the following way:

```
<field fieldName="date_of_birth" returnType="datetime" type="MyProject.Search.ComputedFields.ParsedDateOfBirth,MyProject.Search">
    <name>date of birth</name>
</field>
```

I make sure that the "ParseDateOfBirth" returns a valid date - I tried with both a DateTime object or a string - and in either case I get the following result after inspecting the index with Luke:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share a code snippet of how you are populating the computed field?

Comment: The default item created date is like this <field fieldName="__smallcreateddate"             returnType="string"          >Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.CreatedDate,Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>. Perhaps just store it as string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. You are looking at it in Luke. SOLR encodes the datetime fields so it can handle sorting/filtering in a better way than pure Lucene. If you look at the an item in the SOLR viewer, with a date field. You will find the date is perfect.

I asked the same question a little while ago. The issue is don't look at Luke. Look at the SOLR viewer.

[SOLR datetime fields not readable](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/15370/solr-datetime-fields-not-readable)